# How to pass values - in a loop - to a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

The code for a page which is to be used to test calling a user control dynamically.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestUC.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestUC" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="TestUC" Src="NCCsByRole.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:Placeholder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code behind for this page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TestUC : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            UserControl myUserControl = (UserControl)LoadControl("TeamsByRole.ascx");
            //myUserControl.UserID = i; ******************** NOT WORKING
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the User Control.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TeamsByRole.ascx.cs" Inherits="TeamsByRole" %>
<asp:Literal ID="ltlName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

And the code behind for the User Control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TeamsByRole : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private int _UserID;

    public int UserID
    {
        get { return _UserID; }
        set { _UserID = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myName = "Angela";
        ltlName.Text = "<p>" + myName + "</p>";
    }

}
```

So, I have a page with a reference to a user control. I want to call that user control dynamically and I need to pass a UserID from the page to the User Control as I loop through some data. In my example code above, I am looping from 0 to 4 and the User Control is being 'called' 5 times - as the name 'Angela' is being written to the screen 5 times.

But, how do I pass a UserID (in the loop) to the UserControl? I have a public property of UserID in the User Control but, in the page that is 'calling' the User Control - if I comment in the line ...

```
myUserControl.UserID = i;
```

an error is reported ... 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' and no extension method 'UserID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I pass UserID to my User Control - within the loop that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting your control to `UserControl` but `UserID` is not declared on `UserControl`.  Rather, it is a member of `TeamsByRole`, which is what you should cast to.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        TeamsByRole myUserControl = (TeamsByRole)LoadControl("TeamsByRole.ascx");
        myUserControl.UserID = i;
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Had got to the point where I couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: You are very welcome :).  We've all had those moments.